# How to control android backbutton routes?

Tags: onsen-ui

The default in Onsen is that the app closes/exits when the device backbutton is pressed.  Is there any way to control that in Onsen to also mimic the ons-navigator action/page history?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In case of PhoneGap/Cordova, backbutton event is fired when the backbutton is pressed.
Therefore, you can set the eventhandler s.t.

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
```

In eventhandler function, you can call popPage method of navigator by obtaining the navigator scope s.t.

```
function onBackKeyDown() {
    // Handle the back button
    alert("Backbutton is pressed!");
    var element = document.querySelector( ".navigator-container");
    var scope = angular.element( element ).scope();
    scope.popPage();
}
```

If you are using Monaca, the hybrid application framework based on Cordova, the backbutton event
is not fired. Instead that you can use the .ui file in which the Backbutton event is defined s.t.

```
{
    "event" : {
        "onTapBackButton" : "onBackKeyDown();"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you again @KNaito! You know your stuff.

Comment: This one does not work for me. I can see the alert window, but nothing happens after that. There is also an error, stating a missing "ons" identifier, if I'm trying to call onsen functions directly in onBackKeyDown(). ons.navigator.popPage() for example/

Comment: Thanks, Vladius. .ui file for Monaca is now deprecated. Please use Onsen UI as you say.

Answer (score 2):

No need to handle backbutton event to prevent application being killed.
Onsen-ui Added support to android back-button on ons-navigator and ons-sliding-menu from v1.1.1.

You can check [here](https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/issues/78)

Comment: Second that. Very easy now!

Answer (score 2):

You can controll it with "**disableDeviceBackButtonHandler**" after **ons.ready** event. After that add a event listener for back button and do anything you want.

```
ons.ready(function() {
  ons.disableDeviceBackButtonHandler();

  // Use Cordova handler
  window.document.addEventListener('backbutton', function() {
    // Handle backbutton event
  }, false);
});
```

Just check this article: https://onsen.io/guide/overview.html#HandlingBackButton