# cordova back button fires event listener but app closes anyway

Tags: cordova, mobile, hybrid-mobile-app, back-button, onsen-ui

I have the following code where if the user presses back button on his device, I want to show him a popup before he is able to exit the app. However, this does not work for me. The alert box is showed but the app also closes.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $scope.alertDialog.show();
    }, false);
}, false);
```

Cordova version:6.4.0
And before someone brings it out - cordova.js is included in the index html page.
UI is built using onsenUI with angularJS v1.

Comment: On further debugging the issue is not with cordova, it's actually with onsen-ui. Have a look at - https://onsen.io/v2/docs/guide/angular1/#device-back-button I am still trying to solve as there are multiple listeners in the onsen ui documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. [How to control android backbutton routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24041536/how-to-control-android-backbutton-routes)
The last 0 voted answer is the right one.

> You can controll it with "disableDeviceBackButtonHandler" after
>   ons.ready event. After that add a event listener for back button and
>   do anything you want.

```
ons.ready(function() {
  ons.disableDeviceBackButtonHandler();

  // Use Cordova handler
  window.document.addEventListener('backbutton', function() {
    // Handle backbutton event
  }, false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like following:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
var backbutton=0;
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e) {
       if(backbutton==0){
            backbutton++;
              $scope.alertDialog.show();
             // window.plugins.toast.showShortCenter('Press again to exit');
            $timeout(function(){backbutton=0;},5000);
        }else{
            navigator.app.exitApp();
        }
    }, false);
}, false);
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: The issue is infact with onsen UI. Still not able to figure out though. https://onsen.io/v2/docs/guide/angular1/#device-back-button