# Change back button (android) behaviour when Popup is active, ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to achieve this:

**Scenario 1**

1. - User press back.
2. - Popup appears asking if the user want to exit *
3. - User press back.
4. - App exits*

and

**Scenario 2**

1. User press back.
2. - Popup appears asking if the user want to exit *
3. - User press cancel
4. - Popup closes
5. - User press back.
6. - Popup appears asking if the user want to exit *
7. - User press back
8. - App exits.

I tried using `registerBackButtonAction` and `onHardwareBackButton`combination but I can not get the exit popup to shows the second time (second scenario), it just exit.

This is the code I have now:

```
 var exitPopupControl = function(event) {
            //if I press back again, just go out
            $ionicPlatform.onHardwareBackButton(function(event2){
                navigator.app.exitApp();
            });

          if($state.current.name === "app.startseite"){
                $ionicPopup.confirm({
                    title: 'Exit',
                    template: 'Do you want to exit? <br /><small>Press Back again to exit.</small>'
                }).then(function(res) {
                    if(res) {
                        navigator.app.exitApp();
                        $rootScope.exitPopupShowed = false;

                    } else {
                        console.log('I choose not to left the app');
                        $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(exitPopupControl, 100);
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                window.history.back();
            }
        };

    $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(exitPopupControl, 100);
```

Comment: i did handle like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40283209/cordova-back-button-fires-event-listener-but-app-closes-anyway/40283618#40283618  but no confirmation popup

Answer (score 1):

i did handel with following wa - just change confirmation popup code,

```
var exitPopupControl = function(event) {
            //if I press back again, just go out
            $ionicPlatform.onHardwareBackButton(function(event2){
                navigator.app.exitApp();
            });

          if($state.current.name === "app.startseite"){
                $ionicPopup.confirm({
                    title: 'Exit',
                    template: 'Do you want to exit? <br /><small>Press Back again to exit.</small>'
                }).then(function(res) {
                    if(res) {

                        $rootScope.exitPopupShowed = false;
                        navigator.app.exitApp();

                    } else {
                        return;
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                window.history.back();
            }
        };

    $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(exitPopupControl, 100);
```

**OR** you can try something following:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e) {
       $ionicPopup.confirm({
            title: 'Exit',
            template: 'Do you want to exit? <br /><small>Press Back again to exit.</small>'
        }).then(function(res) {
            if(res) {

                $rootScope.exitPopupShowed = false;
                navigator.app.exitApp();

            } else {
                return;
            }
        });
    }, false);
}, false);
```

**OR** you can try something with toast, i prefer to use this one,

```
var countTimerForCloseApp = false;
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 function showConfirm() {
  if (countTimerForCloseApp) {
   ionic.Platform.exitApp();
  } else {
   countTimerForCloseApp = true;
   showToastMsg($cordovaToast, 'Press again to exit.');
   $timeout(function() {
    countTimerForCloseApp = false;
   }, 2000);
  }

 };

 // Is there a page to go back to?
 if ($ionicHistory.backView()) {
  // Go back in history
  $ionicHistory.backView().go();
 } else {
  // This is the last page: Show confirmation popup
  showConfirm();
 }

 return false;
}, 101);
```

Thank you

Comment: You added a `return` in the popup then function->then->else part, It still exits the app in scenario 2.

Comment: try my **OR** part answer without any function, javascript it self handle back button call in above function,

Comment: and about `return` still exist in scenario 2 because off i think it call your code `$ionicPlatform.onHardwareBackButton(function(event2){
                navigator.app.exitApp();
            });`

Comment: Yes , that is what I do not know how to control.

Comment: just try my **OR** part directly without any function call, please write of in cotroller but not in any `$scope.function`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128147/discussion-between-naitik-and-distante).